# How to set a timer to show the alert message and overlap that alert message with another alert message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, alert

I've written a following script to show the alert message when the mouse-pointer is away from the browser page's content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).mouseleave(function() { 
        alert("your mouse is away"); 
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1>My first PHP program</h1>
  <p>Hello World!</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now what I want to achieve is when the alert message from above script gets displayed, a timer should get started. When the time of five seconds passes and till then if user doesn't click on the Ok button of the displayed alert box another alert box should appear over this alert message saying "Your time has been finished". 
But when the first alert box displays, timer gets started and user clicks ok button before completion of five seconds then the second alert box should not get displayed and the timer again should initialize to zero seconds.
Can anyone help me in this regard, please?
Any kind of help or suggestion will be highly appreciated and accepted.
Waiting for your replies. 
Thanks for spending some of your valuable time to understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</script>
<script>
    var timer;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).mouseleave(function () {
            customAlert("your mouse is away");

        });
    });

    function customAlert(customText) {
        $("#popUp").html(customText);
        timer = setInterval(customAlert2, 5000)

        $("#popUp").dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            buttons: [{
                text: "OK", click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }]

        });

    }

    function customAlert2() {
        $("#popUp2").dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            buttons: [{
                text: "OK", click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]

        });

    }


 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<h1>My first PHP program</h1>
<p>Hello World!</p>
<div id="popUp"></div>
<div id="popUp2">your time is over</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: :Thanks for your answer. But you have made use of jQuery library. Can you please write some code with bare javascript only without making use of any jQuery Ui Library.

Comment: I used jquery ui because I could easily get the OK button press event. So that I can set the timer..

Comment: :Yes, I understood that but can you make this thing happen without using any jQuery UI library? Because my requirement is such that.

Comment: the next alert will show only after pressing OK button.. No other way to hide the alert.